# Run a powershell script from python that uses Web-Administration module

Tags: python, powershell, iis-7

I have a very long powershell script that I need to execute from a python script. 
The powershell script works fine when I run it from command line, but fails when I run it from python.

I've simplified my powershell script to the following code, which reproduces the issue.

Powershell Script:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
Set-WebConfigurationProperty '/system.webServer/proxy' -Name "enabled" -Value "true"
```

Python Script:

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output("powershell [pathToMyPowershellScript]");
```

When I run the powershell script from cmd.exe, it works fine and produces no output.
When I run the python script, it produces the following error:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty : Retrieving the COM class factory for component 
with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following
error: 80040154
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At [pathToMyPowershellScript]:3 char:1
+ Set-WebConfigurationProperty '/system.webServer/proxy' -Name "enabled" -Value "t ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          
 : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WebConfigurationProperty], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,
  Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.SetConfigurationPropertyCommand
```

I'm running IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Professional (x64), with Python 2.7 and Powershell 1.0
Any ideas?

Comment: Also happens when I run the powershell script from ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running the powershell script from the "sysnative" version of cmd:

```
subprocess.check_call("c:\\windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe /c 
                       powershell pathToScript", shell=True)
```

This solves the bitness issue.

Comment: I've been looking for ages for a solution, This did the work!!

Answer (score 1):

Your program may be calling the wrong version of powershell, try explictly calling the exe.

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWoW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

[Heres some related reading you might find interesting.](http://forums.iis.net/post/1979631.aspx)